# Ajax - не конвертирует в объект json с сервера

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Вечер добрый. Есть кнопка в хтмл при клике на нее срабатывает этот скрипт:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {

var optionsGetFile = {
    request: request,
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/test.json',
    async: true,
    data: null,
    headers: 'application/json',
    success: function () {
        var optionsSendFile = {
            request: request,
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/form.php',
            async: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(request.responseText),
            headers: 'application/json',
            success: function () {
                var res = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                console.log(res.logins);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert(request.statusText + ': error');
            }
        };

        ajax(optionsSendFile);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert(request.statusText + ': error. Ошибка в передачи файла!');
    }
};

ajax(optionsGetFile);

});

function ajax(options) {
options.request.open(options.method, options.url, options.async);
options.request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', options.headers);
options.request.send(options.data);
options.request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (options.request.readyState === 4) {
        if (options.request.status === 200) {
            options.success()
        } else {
            options.error();
        }
    }
  };
}
```

**Собственно form.php выглядит следующим образом:**

```
<?php

if(file_get_contents('php://input')) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**Файл test.json:**

```
{
  "logins": [
    "valkiria111",
    "max666",
    "alesana1993"
  ]
}
```

Вопрос вот в чем. Как мне здесь:

```
var res = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(res.logins);
```

Получить объект. console log выводит undefined. Вопрос почему? Т.е он не преобразует json в объект. В итоге json так и остается строкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что *json* - это текстовый формат обмена данными. По сути, когда вы считываете файл - уже прилетает именно строка. А вы её вдобавок обрабатываете

```
JSON.stringify(request.responseText)
```

Получается строка в строке. `stringify` нужно применять к объекту...

В результате с сервера прилетает точно такой же ответ. Грубо говоря:

```
""{\"logins\":[\"valkiria111\",\"max666\",\"alesana1993\"]}""
```

Тогда либо нужно два раза парсить ответ:

```
var res = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(JSON.parse(res));
```

Что конечно не то....

Либо просто отправлять строку без всяких `stringify`

```
data: request.responseText,
```

Comment: выручили)) благодарю. Теперь стало понятно.